# Troubleshooting Connection to Remote Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, unix, virtual-machine, wildfly

I have a bit of a strange situation and I'm not sure if I should be posting here or on serverfault. I have a Wildfly application server running on a linux virtualbox on my local machine. The local application server needs to be able to connect to a remote sql server on the company network. When I try to deploy to the application server it fails with the error:

```
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: No route to host (Host unreachable)
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)"}}
```

I initially thought it might be a connection issue so I went through all the usual troubleshooting steps that I know of. I did a telnet with the name and port of the remote server and that succeeded. I thought perhaps it was a password issue so I tried using squirrel sql to connect to the remote server with password authentication. That succeeded as well. I was able to connect and run queries against the remote db.

What makes it extra strange is that if I boot up a windows virtual box with sql studio installed, the connection from my unix application server to the remote server will start working. I'm not sure what is going on here or even what else to check. Could there be something on Windows that is enabling communication? Why does it only affect my application server and not telenet or squirrel sql?

Comment: Not sure how we're expected to debug connection issues when there's no connection string or datasource configuration shown in the question. Are you using SQL Login credentials (username and password) or Windows authentication? If the latter then the application server needs access to both Active Directory/Kerberos authentication servers as well as the target SQL Server.

Comment: @ AlwaysLearning I went back to my config file to get the connection string for you and found something embarrassing. I'm not sure if it just didn't save or if it got rolled back somehow, but my connection URL was still pointed at an old datasource hosted on my windows machine. How I missed that I'll never know but as soon as I changed it to the correct location the connection worked.